# how to match a spark RDD with results from JdbcRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a mydata:RDD[Vertex] where each Vertex has an id property. I also have data from mysql in a dbdata:JdbcRDD[String], where the first position in each string is occupied by an id value that matches the one in Vertex.id in the RDD collection.

I want to fill each Vertex's variable with data from the JdbcRDD[String], but I don't the more efficient way to match the two datasets. I am trying this but it's not working:

```
mydata.map(x => val arow = dbdata.filter { y => y.split(",")(0).toString == x.id }.collect
           x.prop1 = arow(1)
           // ... for all other values in arow
)
```

However, I get a

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations;
```

so I guess my approach is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem sounds like a good fit for a join operation. The following code snippet should do the trick

```scala
val mydata: RDD[Vertex] = ...
val dbdata: JdbcRDD[String] = ...

val mydataKV = mydata.map(x => (x.id, x))
val dbdataKV = dbdata.map(x => ((x.split(",")(0), x)))

val result = mydataKV.join(dbdataKV).mapValues{
  case (vertex, db) =>
    // fill vertex fields
    vertex.prop1 = db.split(",")(1)
    ...

    vertex
}
```

Comment: looks like what I need, the only problem is that I have: value copy is not a member of Vertex... should I have to add something to my class?

Comment: ok, I think I got it: I have to define a copy method that will store all the values I need, is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I defined the `Vertex` class to be a case class and there you have such a method. In your case, you simply have to fill in the fields I assume. I've updated my answer.

Comment: no problems!!! the very last thing is: I'd like the result to be stored again in mydata or in mydataKV, not in result, since all the new values have been stored in my Vertex classes... any hint on that?

Comment: `mydata` and `mydataKV` are only logical representations of your data. The actual data is only calculated when you call a Spark action. Thus, it is no problem to assign the resulting `RDD` to a new variable called `result`.

Comment: yes but then I should refer to "result" to see updated data, right? Now if I ask mydata to print the new assigned values, I get null values

Comment: Yes, you should refer to `result` in order to obtain the calculated results.

Comment: since my Vertex has properties like Array[String], I'd like to retain mydata and update that in order not to have to copy back all the stuff... is that something wrong in this approach of mine?

Comment: You're not copying the data but rather transforming it. An `RDD` represents an intermediate state of your data flow graph where you perform calculations by applying transformations to your data. It is possible to checkpoint data but in most cases you're only interested in the final result which will be materialized.